# How to automatically correlate two types of data with a pattern in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, counter, correlation, nonetype

I generated this csv text file:

```
{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id,begin,end,Expressor
joy
13108,15,33,Physical sensations
sadness
13123,252,258,Voice
trust
11647,1564,1570,Looking behaviour
joy
11647,1564,1570,Looking behaviour
11625,1524,1557,Facial expression
trust
joy
11625,1524,1557,Facial expression
joy
11743,1657,1670,Facial expression
joy
13175,1921,1935,Facial expression
anger
11879,2023,2041,Looking behaviour
disgust
11948,2490,2496,Body movements
disgust
11940,2469,2482,Facial expression
trust
12024,2641,2676,Facial expression
joy
12024,2641,2676,Facial expression
12134,2728,2757,Looking behaviour
```

which includes results taken from an .xmi file of an annotated corpus for emotional character relation.

First, I'd like to count the occurrences of every type of 'Expressor's (8 fixed types in total) and print the result as a list **without** the 'None' value, which is resulting in a wrong end count of all expressors (adding 72 to the sum()):

```
    0 - None, 72
    1 - Physical sensations, 1
    2 - Voice, 1
    3 - Looking behaviour, 4
    4 - Facial expression, 7
    ...
```

In addition, I'd like to be able to connect the emotion(s) with its (their) expressor(s). The file displays an emotion, and the expressors bellow it are connected with it.

An emotion could have one or more than an expressor. E.g.:

```
joy
11647,1564,1570,Looking behaviour
11625,1524,1557,Facial expression
```

And an expressor could be correlated to more than one emotion. E.g.:

```
trust
joy
11625,1524,1557,Facial expression
```

**So, the pattern is:**

Emotion(s),

its (their) expressor(s)

- So, a specific correlation ends when a new emotion(s) follows in the next line and the pattern above is repeated for the new correlation.

My goal is to be able to correlate them and count each correlation of an emotion to its expressors. E.g.:

```
Joy: 'Looking behaviour': 4, 'Physical sensations': 2, 'Facial expression': 7..... #etc.
Fear: 'Looking behaviour': 9, 'Physical sensations': 3, 'Facial expression': 5.....#etc
```

My code that gives me the csv text file is as follows:

```
def emex_count():
    with open('emex_count.txt', 'w') as f:
        cf = csv.DictWriter(f, ['{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id', 'begin', 'end'\
                                , 'Expressor'], extrasaction='ignore')
        cf.writeheader()
        for rel_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterRelation",ns):
            if rel_node.attrib['Relation']=="Expressor":
                source = rel_node.attrib['Governor']
                target = rel_node.attrib['Dependent']
                for span_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterEmotion",ns):
                    if span_node.attrib[my_id]==source:
                        print(span_node.attrib['Emotion'])
                        print(span_node.attrib['Emotion'], file=f)
                    if span_node.attrib[my_id]==target:
                        print(span_node.attrib)
                        cf.writerow(span_node.attrib)
    with open('expericount.txt') as f:
        cf = csv.DictReader(f)
        val = collections.Counter(d['Expressor'] for d in cf)
        print(sum(val.values()))
        for n,(ex, number) in enumerate(val.items()):
            print('{} - {}, {}'.format(n, ex, number))
```

Is there a way to be able to automate the correlation between the emotions and their expressors?

I hope my question is understanble :'D

Answer (score 0):

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a good library for this sort of work. Here is something for the first part:

```
import pandas as pd

# with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as a:
   # a = a.read()


a="""joy
13108,15,33,Physical sensations
sadness
13123,252,258,Voice
trust
11647,1564,1570,Looking behaviour
joy
11647,1564,1570,Looking behaviour
11625,1524,1557,Facial expression
trust
joy
11625,1524,1557,Facial expression
joy
11743,1657,1670,Facial expression
joy
13175,1921,1935,Facial expression
anger
11879,2023,2041,Looking behaviour
disgust
11948,2490,2496,Body movements
disgust
11940,2469,2482,Facial expression
trust
12024,2641,2676,Facial expression
joy
12024,2641,2676,Facial expression
12134,2728,2757,Looking behaviour"""

exprsrs = [i for i in a.splitlines() if not i.isalpha()]
df = pd.DataFrame(exprsrs, columns=['expressor'])
df['expressor'] = df.expressor.str.split(',').str[-1]
df.expressor.value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Facial expression      7
Looking behaviour      4
Voice                  1
Physical sensations    1
Body movements         1
Name: expressor, dtype: int64
```

And for the second part:

```
final = []
running = []
for line in a.splitlines():    
    if line.isalpha():
        running.append(line.strip())
    else:
        for r in running:
            final.append(f'{r},{line}')
        running = []

df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=['whole'])

df['expression'] = df.whole.str.split(',').str[0]
df['expressor'] = df.whole.str.split(',').str[-1]

df.groupby('expression')['expressor'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
expression  expressor          
anger       Looking behaviour      1
disgust     Body movements         1
            Facial expression      1
joy         Facial expression      4
            Looking behaviour      1
            Physical sensations    1
sadness     Voice                  1
trust       Facial expression      2
            Looking behaviour      1
Name: expressor, dtype: int64
```

If you want it as a dictionary, you could do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = df.groupby('expression')['expressor'].value_counts().to_dict()
new_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in d.items():
    new_dict[k[0]][k[1]] = v

final_dict = dict(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'anger': {'Looking behaviour': 1},
 'disgust': {'Body movements': 1, 'Facial expression': 1},
 'joy': {'Facial expression': 4,
         'Looking behaviour': 1,
         'Physical sensations': 1},
 'sadness': {'Voice': 1},
 'trust': {'Facial expression': 2, 'Looking behaviour': 1}}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I run the first part under `with open('emex_count.txt') as a:` instead of having the text file in the code.  `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines`

Comment: you mean `with open('emex_count.txt', a=a.read()) as a:` ? It displays now this error message: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: check my edit. I've added a little code snippet. uncomment it and use it in your code.